# проброс RDP на miktotik rb3011

Tags: mikrotik

Подскажите пожалуйста как пробросить на mikrotik RB3011 порты на доступ к RDP, данный девайс ковыряю впервые поэтому сильно не смейтесь. Понимаю всю абсурдность того что имея возможность понять VPN но всё же нужно на пару дней открыть RDP. нашел несколько инструкций как это сделать но результата это не принесло...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно пробросить наружу порт 3389. Можно гуглить "проброс портов на микротик" или зайти на перую попавшуюся инструкцию: https://lantorg.com/article/probros-portov-na-mikrotik . Ставьте надежный пароль, потому что сразу боты набегут!

Comment: Проброс идёт с перенаправлением как в моем случае с 22375 на 3389.. но с 3389 на 3389 я тоже пробовал не проходит

Comment: А Вы пробуете "снаружи", когда пробуете? или так - пробросил порт наружу, и из той же сети пробуете к нему подключиться по внешнему IP?

Comment: Пробую именно снаружи подключаться